# First problem from Slater & Frank book on mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I can't solve the very first problem and have no one to help me (I'm self-studying it in these vacations):

*"1. A particle moves in a vertical line under the action of gravity and a viscous force $(-av)$ where $v$ is its velocity. Show that the velocity at any time is given by
$v = (v_0 + mg/a) e^{-(a/m)t} - mg/a.$
Show that this solution reduces [...]."*

**What I did is**:

The resultant force is $mg - av$, and so by Newton's second law $m dv/dt = mg - av$.

Since $m$, $a$, and $g$ are constants in this case, this is a first order ODE, which also happens to be a separable one.

We rewrite it as a relation between differentials: $m dv/(mg - av) = dt$.

But I have no idea how to integrate the left side relative to $v$. Despite the fact that the exercise already gave the solution, $v(t)$.

Am I doing it right? Or maybe there is a simpler way using methods specials from mathematical mechanics?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: You're on the right track, just do the integral or [get a computer to do it for you](http://www.integral-calculator.com/).